# Shouldn't i run vacuum analyze together? Should i run vacuum and analyze separately? Assuming large delete and updates are done

Tags: greenplum, vacuum

Assuming large delete and updates are done on a GP table.

Shouldn't i run vacuum analyze together? Should i run vacuum and analyze separately?. The GP best practice document says "Do not run vacuum analyze"
http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4300/pdf/GPDB43BestPractices.pdf

What is the order it runs when i run vacuum analyze? Is there any best practice around the order to run vacuum and analyze? Why Pivotal says do not run both of them together?

Answer (score 1):

It's safer to run ANALYZE before running VACUUM to correct any potential inaccurate row count estimate when a table is significantly bloated.

Because ANALYZE uses block-level sampling, a table with a high ratio of blocks containing no valid rows can cause ANALYZE to set the *reltuples* column in *pg_class* catalog table to an inaccurate value, leading to unoptimized query plans. The VACUUM command produces a more accurate count and when run after ANALYZE will correct an inaccurate row count estimate.

Comment: Thank you very much ielizaga